# How do I generate an in-line, client side warning in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There's plenty of ways to generate client side errors that prevent the user from saving form data, however, I want to allow the user to continue and save if they wish. I still want a message to pop up saying the data is suspect but if the user chooses, they can continue and save the data. What's the best way of doing this in rails 4?

Comment: Form data validation is a part of business use-cases. If validation is not required, you can go ahead and save it into the DB. What's stopping you?

Comment: He's asking about what's the best way of doing it, not where the problem is. Generating a simple example's scaffold will make you a full form where you can see the way in which Rails deal with it.
The best one? I'm also wondering.

Comment: Yeh - I know I can save anything I want into the database, but I want to check the data in the browser and warn the user on the fly if it's suspect. The user can override that and save it anyway if they want. A good example would be a phone number. Let's say the user types in `after 5PM 91548634, 0403456789 before`. That's not going to pass a phone number regular expression. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement the pseudo validation logic in javascript.